# Key expected String[] but value was a java.lang.String

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting issues of getting my USER KEY and it returned as null even if there's a username.

Thing is I am just trying to get my username.

I am currently using firebase database

```
class NewMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message)

        supportActionBar?.title="Select User"

       /*
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()

        adapter.add(UserItem())
        adapter.add(UserItem())
        adapter.add(UserItem())



        new_message_list.adapter = adapter
         */

        fetchusers()

    }
    companion object {
        val USER_KEY = "USER_KEY"
    }
    private fun fetchusers(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("NewMessage", it.toString())
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if (user != null){
                        adapter.add(UserItem(user))

                    }
                }
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->

                    val userItem = item as UserItem

                    val intent = Intent(view.context, ChatLogActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, userItem.user.username)
                    startActivity(intent)

                    finish()

                }

                new_message_list.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
        }
    }


class UserItem(val user: User): Item<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int){
        //list stuff
        viewHolder.itemView.username_textview_new.text = user.username

        Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.imageview_new_msg)
    }
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.user_row_new_message
    }
}
```

This one really frustrated me for hours. I needed this for my chat log title for each person
Maybe I should skip this?
I am just new to android development

Can anyone help?

[error in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMyQ.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  We also need to see the contents of your database to understand what you're expecting to happen with this query.